# MySQL unable to update multiple rows from while loop

Tags: php, mysql

I have a while loop. It is within a form.I want to update all rows from while loop when entering submit button. Below is the code of while loop.

```
<form method="POST" action="insert.php" n>
  <table>
                    <?php                           
                     $i =0;
                     $link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'shibu');
                     $sql = "select `cus_id`, `mobile`, `date`, `time`, `bal`,
                            sum(`d1` + `d2` + `d3`) as `credit`,
                            sum(`d1` + `d2` + `d3`) + `bal` as `nbal`
                            from `finale`";
                        $result=mysqli_query($link, $sql);
                        $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
                        if($count == 0){
                        ?>
                        <tr> 
                        <th><?php echo 'No Records Founds!' .mysqli_error($link); ?></th> 
                        </tr>
                        <?php 
                        }else{
                            while($sql_result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                        ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $i += 1; ?></td>
<td><input type="text" name="cus_id[]" value="<?php echo $sql_result['cus_id']; ?>" ></td>
<td><input type="text" name="mobile[]" value="<?php echo $sql_result['mobile']; ?>" ></td>
<td><input type="text" name="date[]" value="<?php echo $sql_result['date']; ?>" ></td>
<td><input type="text" name="time[]" value="<?php echo $sql_result['time']; ?>"</td>
<td><input type="text" name="credit[]" value="<?php echo $sql_result['credit']; ?>"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="bal[]" value="<?php echo $sql_result['bal']; ?>"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="nbal[]" value="<?php echo $sql_result['nbal']; ?>"></td>
</tr>
    <?php
    }
    }
    ?>
 </table>
<input name="submit" type="submit"  />
</form>
```

This is my update query.

```
<?php
$date = date("d/m/Y");

$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'shibu');

$st = "UPDATE `finale` SET `bal` = '$nbal' WHERE `date` = '$today' and `cus_id` = '$cus_id' ";

$stmt = mysqli_query($link, $st);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);                                         
                }

if(!$stmt){ 
echo "error". mysqli_error($link);
}else{
echo "Successful.";
}
```

My problem is when I enter `submit` button, `bal` field not updated but successful message comes .

I need your help heartily.

Comment: I used `where` in small letter. Now I edited with capital letter. But till now unable to  update.

Comment: `$stmt = mysqli_query($link, $st);

mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);` that could be failing you here. Remove the `mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);`

Comment: your first `$sql` query, is also failing; missing a double quote.

Comment: In the SQL - you use $today, is this supposed to be $date set at the start of that script?

Comment: `n>` < what's that "n" doing in the form? and what is the date column's type? and where is `$cus_id` defined?

Comment: I noticed the edit and you didn't say anything about it, you just overwrote the question/defaced it. If you're going to be editing "on the fly", then I can't be of much more help here. I've left the question.

Comment: I have corrected everything . date column's type is varchar(255). $cus_id  is $_POST['cus_id']

Comment: Sorry. I apologize. I have changed code as before. Plz don't leave

Comment: Please give me the name of the page where the form resides.

Comment: In the db table "finale": you have the field "balance" (as in update statement) or "bal" (as in select statement)? Or both? Please provide the list of the db table's column names in the question.

Comment: It should be `bal` instead of `balance`

Comment: Ok. @rockya, I'm working on a solution for you, but I have some unclarities. I need to ask you some questions. Ok? How many html table rows are you expecting? If you are not grouping by "cus_id" in the select, then there is only one html table row displayed. This is not what you want, right?

Comment: In the while loop, at least 100+ rows there. I want to update all the rows in the ` bal` field.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157187/discussion-between-aendeerei-and-rocky-a).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
/*
 * =================================
 * Enable internal report functions.
 * =================================
 * 
 * This enables the exception handling, 
 * e.g. mysqli will not throw PHP warnings anymore, but mysqli exceptions 
 * (mysqli_sql_exception). They are catched in the try-catch block.
 * 
 * MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR: Report errors from mysqli function calls.
 * MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT: Throw a mysqli_sql_exception for errors instead of warnings. 
 * 
 * See:
 *      http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-driver.php
 *      http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-driver.report-mode.php
 *      http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.constants.php
 */
$mysqliDriver = new mysqli_driver();
$mysqliDriver->report_mode = (MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

try {
    // Create a db connection.
    $connection = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'shibu');

    /*
     * ================================
     * Operations upon form submission.
     * ================================
     */
    if (isset($_POST['updateButton'])) {
        $today = date('d/m/Y');

        $customerIds = $_POST['customerId'];
        $dates = $_POST['date'];
        $newBalances = $_POST['newBalance'];

        // @todo To delete. These line(s) are just for testing.
        echo '<pre>' . print_r($customerIds, TRUE) . '</pre>';
        echo '<pre>' . print_r($dates, TRUE) . '</pre>';
        echo '<pre>' . print_r($newBalances, TRUE) . '</pre>';

        // Iterate through the dates list and update only the records from today.
        foreach ($dates as $key => $date) {
            if ($date === $today) {
                $customerId = $customerIds[$key];
                $newBalance = $newBalances[$key];

                $sql = 'UPDATE `finale` 
                        SET `bal` = ? 
                        WHERE 
                            `cus_id` = ? AND 
                            `date` = ?';

                // Prepare the SQL statement for execution.
                $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);

                /*
                 * Bind the variables for the parameter markers (?). The first 
                 * argument of mysqli_stmt::bind_param is a string that contains one 
                 * or more characters which specify the types for the corresponding bind variables.
                 */
                $bound = $statement->bind_param('dis', $newBalance, $customerId, $date);

                // Execute the prepared statement.
                $executed = $statement->execute();

                // Close the prepared statement and deallocate the statement handle.
                $statement->close();
            }
        }
    }

    /*
     * =========================
     * Fetch the customers list.
     * =========================
     */

    $sql = 'SELECT 
                `cus_id` AS `customerId`,
                `date`,
                `time`,
                `bal` AS `balance`,
                (`d1` + `d2` + `d3`) AS `credit`,
                (`d1` + `d2` + `d3` + `bal`) AS `newBalance` 
            FROM `finale` 
            ORDER BY 
                `customerId` ASC,
                `date` DESC';

    // Prepare the SQL statement for execution.
    $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);

    /*
     * Execute the prepared statement. When executed, any parameter markers 
     * which exist will automatically be replaced with the appropriate data.
     */
    $executed = $statement->execute();

    // Get the result set from the prepared statement.
    $result = $statement->get_result();

    // Fetch data.
    $customers = array();
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        $customers = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    }

    // @todo To delete. These line(s) are just for testing.
    echo '<pre>' . print_r($customers, TRUE) . '</pre>';

    /*
     * Free the memory associated with the result. You should 
     * always free your result when it is not needed anymore.
     */
    $result->close();

    /*
     * Close the prepared statement. It also deallocates the statement handle.
     * If the statement has pending or unread results, it cancels them 
     * so that the next query can be executed.
     */
    $statement->close();

    // Close the database connection.
    $connection->close();
} catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e) {
    echo 'An error occurred during your request. Please try again or call the administrator.';
    // Log the exception to a log file.
    // logError($e);
    exit();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // Handle the rest of the exceptions here...
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head -->

        <title>Demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <?php
        if ($customers) {
            ?>
            <form action="" method="post">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>No.</td>
                        <td>Customer id</td>
                        <td>Date</td>
                        <td>Time</td>
                        <td>Credit</td>
                        <td>Old balance</td>
                        <td>New balance</td>
                    </tr>

                    <?php
                    foreach ($customers as $key => $customer) {
                        ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <?php echo $key + 1; ?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" name="customerId[]" value="<?php echo $customer['customerId']; ?>" readonly />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" name="date[]" value="<?php echo $customer['date']; ?>" readonly />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" name="time[]" value="<?php echo $customer['time']; ?>" readonly />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" name="credit[]" value="<?php echo $customer['credit']; ?>" readonly />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" name="balance[]" value="<?php echo $customer['balance']; ?>" readonly />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" name="newBalance[]" value="<?php echo $customer['newBalance']; ?>" readonly />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                </table>
                <br/>
                <button name="updateButton" type="submit" value="Update">
                    Update
                </button>
            </form>
            <?php
        } else {
            ?>
            <div>
                No records found.
            </div>
            <?php
        }
        ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Words can’t express my gratitude to you. I’ll just say thanks. My problem solved. I have learnt too much from you. Anyway thank you again.